# Problemas com $('').height();

Tags: javascript, jquery

O meu site é basicamente assim:

[img http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3266/gr3pg3kqokxkkduzg.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/3266/gr3pg3kqokxkkduzg.jpg)

Eu faço o seguinte script para manter o bloco #right da altura do #left:

```
$('#right').height($('#left').height());
```

mas quando eu coloco algum conteudo no bloco left, o bloco right fica um pouco menor:

[img http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2332/k1wrdjdpgsc5x56zg.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2332/k1wrdjdpgsc5x56zg.jpg)

Caso queiram ver o site: http://itbinds.tk/tutoriais/informatica/ompp/ompp.html

Como devo fazer?

Desde já, Obrigado!!!

Comment: O código está correto, [vide exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqcqtahq/1/). Talvez esteja esquecendo de incluir mais alguma informação. Se possível, trabalhe com o problema real, ao invés de "#left" e "#right" use as classes/ids que está manipulando no site.

Comment: Se queres manter esses blocos com a mesma altura tens de correr essa linha de código a cada vez que um deles mudar de tamanho/altura. Já tentaste isso?

Comment: Vou fugir um pouco da sua pergunta. Se eu entendi bem, o seu problema é com o layout. O lugar ideal para resolver problemas de layout é no CSS sem envolver JavaScript. O layout do seu site é muito próximo de um _duas colunas_ clássico. Eu recomendaria buscar artigos sobre esse layout e adaptar ao seu problema. [Esse artigo](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/) lista alguns exemplos de layout com CSS.

Comment: @Sergiopereira mas parceiro, o height eh todo bugado, fica mt mais facil ele deixar uma altura  maleavel com JS

Comment: @AndreyHartung entendo seu ponto de vista, mas eu vejo diferente. Se fosse fácil como soa, não estaríamos aqui procurando respostas para esse problema. Minha sugestão foi apenas para considerar uma solução apenas com CSS pois esse é basicamente um problema já resolvido e com muitos exemplos por aí. Eu nunca tive sorte a longo prazo com soluções em JS para esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como dito acima, a melhor maneira de resolver esse problema seria com css. Se vc nao se importa em usar javascript tai a solucao : `$('#publicidade').height($('#corpo').outerHeight());`

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/ 
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Boa leitura